# webView Caching is not working with loadDataWithBaseURL()

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am loading some html string into a webview in my app. My code:

```
public class AboutUsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    String url = CommonUtils.aboutUsUrl;
    private FetchTask fetchTask = null;
    WebView webView = null;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrapper, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(
                getSherlockActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // check whether internet connection is available or not
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getSherlockActivity());
        boolean hasConnection = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if(hasConnection) {
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            fetchTask = new FetchTask();
            fetchTask.execute();
        } else {
            MainActivity.networkAvailabilityNotice(getSherlockActivity());
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(
                    WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }
    }

    protected class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // data fetching from JSON feed
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", result, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        }

    }
}
```

Problem is that - the cache in't working i.e. the webpage is not showing in offline mode. I managed to provide cache in past with loadURL() method. How to provide webview cache in offline mode with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I didn't any find any built-in method to cache the contents just like typical webview. So I saved the text in a .txt file and read that content in offline mode. :)